# Add data from one Azure DB table to another Azure DB table

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I Want add data from one Azure DB table to another Azure DB table But same server and same table format. this task i want to run every 5 min. how can i do it any idea about it? i'm founded use elastic database but i want to do different way

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AuditLog](
[AuditLogId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[TableName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[UserId] [int] NULL,
[EmployeeName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Application.AuditLog] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([AuditLogId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]) ON [PRIMARY] 
TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO


     INSERT INTO [DBTwo].[dbo].
     [AuditLog(TableName,UserId,EmployeeName,Actions)
     SELECT TableName,UserId,EmployeeName,Actions
     FROM [CemexTenant].[Application].[AuditLog]
     DELETE FROM [DBOne].[dbo].[AuditLog]
```

Comment: First you write some SQL to do it: `insert into table 1 select * from table2`. Then you use Azure automation to run some powershell that runs that SQL.  Please post some sample table definitions etc. and exaplain how you want to copy the data across. Delete everything in target and copy it all over or only copy across a subset. You can also use Azure Data Factory to do it.

Comment: yes copy data from first DB table then put into 2nd DB table and delete every thing in first DB table. i'm already wrote sample query but that one working on local server not in Azure

Comment: OK so this is two different databases. This might be easier in Azure Data Factory. I suggest you create an Azure data factory instance in Azure and use the Copy Data Wizard to do this. Azure Data Factory has built in scheduling so you can do it all in here. https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/cloud/cloud-data/using-copy-wizard-azure-data-factory/